# Use php mail function with 2 different smtp servers

Tags: php, bash, email, smtp

I have a PHP app that using mail function to send emails. As sendmail app I using MSMTP.
So the problem is that I need to send mail at one inbox with the first SMTP server and to another with the second SMTP server.
For example:
If mail should be sent to Gmail if it will use Gmail SMTP server. If mail should be sent to inbox at another SMTP server it will use my SMTP server.

I thought about using bash script that will use MSMTP with different configs depends on "To" string. But I not pretty sure how to do this.

Comment: would it not be easier to use PHPmailer libary? https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: I afraid that it will be hard to replace mail with phpmail in app that I use. Also I didn't find a way to use different smtp servers depends on recipients emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a bash script. I sure that it can be much better but at least it works.
This should be set as a sendmail_path.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -r recipient
if [[ $recipient = *'@newcbl.ru' ]]; then
  echo -e $recipient"\n""$(</dev/stdin)" | msmtp -tC /etc/msmtprc_cbl
else
  echo -e $recipient"\n""$(</dev/stdin)" | msmtp -t
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use pear mail package and an iterator? Using some IF statements inside the iterator (for loop) you can call whatever logic to include/exclude the smtp server.

```
require_once "Mail.php";

$smtpServers[0] = "smtp.gmail.com";
$smtpServers[1] = "smtp.server1.com";
$smtpServers[2] = "smtp.whatever.com";

for($copies=0;$copies < 2; $i++) {
       $host = $smtpServers[2];
       if (stristr($to, 'gmail.com')) { $host = $smtpServers[0]; } 
       if (stristr($to, 'hotmail.com')) { $host = $smtpServers[1]; } 

       $username = "youremail@example.com";
       $password = "your email password";
       $port = "465";
       $to = "address_form_will_send_TO@example.com";
       $email_from = "youremail@example.com";
       $email_subject = "Subject Line Here:" ;
       $email_body = "whatever you like" ;
       $email_address = "reply-to@example.com";

       $headers = array ('From' => $email_from, 'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $email_subject, 'Reply-To' => $email_address);
       $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host' => $host, 'port' => $port, 'auth'        => true, 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password));
       $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $email_body);


       if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
              echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
       } else {
              echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
       }
}
```